# AngularJS Directive not called when reset form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an issue when using a directive inside a form when I click on button type reset. My issue can be found and reproduced on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-5bvysv). My directive is a basic directive which put the input in error state if the given input is inferior to 1900. Please be aware that I can not change the type of the button, it must remain `type=reset`.

**To reproduce the normal behavior of the directive**

1. Enter 100 inside the input => you will see that the input is in error state
2. Enter 2000 inside the input => you will see that the input has no error

**To reproduce the bugged behavior of the directive**

1. Enter 100 inside the input => input is in error state
2. Click the reset button => input content is resetted, but the input remain in error state whereas it should has no error

Here is the HTML code :

```
<form name="dateForm">
    <div class="form-group" name="dateForm">
        <label for="usr">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="year" name="year"
               valid-year="true" ng-model="$ctrl.year" year-min="1900">
    </div>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
angular.module('app', requires)
.directive('validYear', function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
            if (attrs.validYear === 'true') {
                if (!modelCtrl) {
                    return;
                }
                modelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                    console.log('--> call to directive');

                    if (angular.isDefined(attrs.yearMax) && parseInt(value) > parseInt(attrs.yearMax)) {
                        modelCtrl.$setValidity('validYear', false);
                    } else {
                        modelCtrl.$setValidity('validYear', true);
                    }
                    if (angular.isDefined(attrs.yearMin) && parseInt(value) < parseInt(attrs.yearMin)) {
                        modelCtrl.$setValidity('validYear', false);
                    } else {
                        if (angular.isDefined(attrs.yearMax) && parseInt(value) > parseInt(attrs.yearMax)) {
                            modelCtrl.$setValidity('validYear', false);
                        } else {
                            modelCtrl.$setValidity('validYear', true);
                        }
                    }
                    return value;
                });
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: when click reset , the '--> call to directive' did not trigger. So the state would not change.

Comment: So why the directive is not called and how do I get it called?

Comment: I have two idea. one is override the methods 'reset' . the another is use  function  'watch' to watch the value '$ctrl.year'

Answer (score 0):

First, of all you validation directive is very strange -- if you change value from controller, it wont work... That's strange. (Or this is desired?) Please, take a look how you should add validator in angularjs documentation.

Second, you main problem is not running validation but that 'reset' button do not change model value. You'd better do not rely on such native things, you can override reset button behavior:

```
<button type="reset" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();$ctrl.year=null"...
```